Can we match route based on a pattern
We are using YARP to route requests to different endpoints. We have a requirement where any url starting with "/secured" should be forwarded to a specific cluster endpoint. For example, all the following paths need to be sent to cluster1

/secured
/secured/
/secured/xyz
/secured/xyz/abc
/securedxyz
/securedxyz/
/securedxyz/abc

To achieve it we are configuring the routes as below:
{
 "AllowedHosts": "*",
 "ReverseProxy": {
   "Routes": {
     "route1" : {
       "ClusterId": "cluster1",
       "Match": {
         "Path": "/secured{any1}"
       }
     },
     "route2" : {
       "ClusterId": "cluster1",
       "Match": {
         "Path": "/secured{any1}/{*any}"
       }
     },
    "route3" : {
       "ClusterId": "cluster1",
       "Match": {
         "Path": "/secured/{*any}"
       }
     }
   },
   "Clusters": {
     "cluster1": {
       "Destinations": {
         "destination1": {
           "Address": "https://secured.com/"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}

Can we configure the path as a pattern that will match all the routes specified above? I have tried the configuration below, but it doesn't work. I want to reduce the number of route specifications make the config shorter.
    "Path": "/secured(.*)"


How about use the middleware conditionally.

Use:
/secured/{**catch-all}

That will match the rest of the URL after /secured

Will that match paths "/securedxyz" or "/secured"?

You could try this workaround.
{
 "AllowedHosts": "*",
 "ReverseProxy": {
   "Routes": {
     "route1" : {
       "ClusterId": "cluster1",
       "Match": {
         "Path": "/secured/{**catch-all}"
       }
     }
   },
   "Clusters": {
     "cluster1": {
       "Destinations": {
         "destination1": {
           "Address": "https://secured.com/"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}

Then use middleware to modify the route before app.UseRouting() and app.MapReverseProxy(); so that the path will match /secured/{**catch-all}
        var app = builder.Build();

        app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            var pathValue = context.Request.Path.Value;
            if (pathValue.StartsWith("/secured"))
            {
                //check if the 8th char is not "/", which is /secured{any1} pattern, insert a "/"
                if (pathValue[8] != '/')
                {
                    pathValue=pathValue.Insert(8,"/");
                    context.Request.Path = pathValue;
                }
            }
            await next();
        });
        app.UseRouting();
...
        app.MapReverseProxy();


/secured{**catch-all} should match anything starting with /secured
